# Statistics problem. How do I draw a sample size x from a population/matrix where N(1,3) mean = 1 and sd = 3 in R

Tags: r

Statistics problem.  How do I draw a sample size x from a population/matrix where N(1,3) mean = 1 and sd = 3 in R can i use a filter or sample function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This is a programming question for people who program in R. It may not seem like one depending on your area of specialty, but for those of us working with R in data analysis areas, this is a very on track question with a programatic answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function you’re looking for is called [`rnorm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html). In general, when looking for a function in R it helps to just search for the name of the distribution (so in this case, “R normal distribution”).

Inside R, you can also use the command `??normal` to search for help pages containing the term “normal”. This will also contain the desired function but unfortunately it will be harder to find since the results are ordered alphabetically rather than by relevance.

Comment: Would the code look like "S1 <- rnorm(pmatrix(25,1,7.259224)" ?

Comment: if you type ?rnorm in rstudios console you will see this `dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE)`. based on it you would create your function as such: `S1 = rnorm(25, 1, 7.259224)`